# react-native navigator not calling renderScene method

Tags: javascript, navigation, react-native

I'm trying to use `react-native` navigator.

This is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
          AppRegistry,
          StyleSheet, 
          Text, 
          View,
          Navigator,
       } from 'react-native';
import Login from './components/Login/login';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    console.log("in default class constructor")
    super()
    this.renderScene = this.renderScene.bind(this);
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator){
    console.log("route: ",route)
    if(route.name == 'Login'){
      return <Login navigator={navigator} />
    }
    else if(route.name == 'Home'){
      return <Home navigator={navigator} />
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("in render")
      return (   
        <Navigator 
           initialRoute={{ name: 'Login' }}
           renderScene = {this.renderScene}
       />
    );
  }
}
```

This is my login.js

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { 
              AppRegistry,
              StyleSheet, 
              Text, 
              View, 
              Navigator,
            } from 'react-native';

    class Login extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>  <Text>Domain: </Text> </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    height: 1000,
    width: 350
  }
});    
module.exports = Login;
```

The console statement in `renderScene` method is not getting hit. If I just render `Login` it is working, but if I use `Navigator` as mentioned above it doesn't render anything on screen but compiles without errors.

Console output:

```
 in default class constructor

 in render
```